# Pyspark : Conditional Join on timestamps columns

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes :

```
df1
id, timestamp1
a, 2023-01-01 10:00:00
a, 2023-01-01 13:00:00
b, 2023-01-01 11:00:00
b, 2023-01-01 15:00:00

df2
id, timestamp2
a, 2023-01-01 10:05:00
a, 2023-01-01 13:15:00
c, 2023-01-01 11:00:00
c, 2023-01-01 15:00:00
```

I would like to join them based on the id and the timestamp columns, only if the difference between both timestamps is less than 10 minutes (we can use abs() as timestamp1 can be before or after timestamp2).

So my desired output would be :

```
df_joined
id, timestamp1, timestamp2
a, 2023-01-01 10:00:00, 2023-01-01 10:05:00
```

Here's what I tried but didnt work :

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, on=[df1.id==df2.id, (df1.timestamp1.cast("long") - df2.timestamp2.cast("long")) < 600], how="inner")
```

Thank you for any tip or help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this conditional in join statement, you could perform a common join between the two dataframes and after this, use where or filter clause to execute your conditions.

Something like this:

df1.join(df2, ['id']).where(abs(expr('timestamp1 - timestamp2')) < expr('INTERVAL 10 MINUTES'))

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the pyspark.sql.functions.abs on your join condition.